# What's the difference between int and unsigned-int value representations in bits in C

Tags: c, int, unsigned-integer

I noticed by experiment that in `unsigned int` the value of a number is represented in 32 bit even if the number is taking 1-bit space, the rest of the bits would take 0 as a value. While in `int`, the value is being put in the bits needed with just 1 more bit added for the sign. Can someone please explain to me what's that?

Comment: The smallest data type in C is `char`. The smallest addressable unit in most computers is `byte`. The question is unclear.

Comment: @EugeneSh. `byte` is not a datatype in C though.

Comment: @EliSadoff I didn't say it is...

Comment: @EugeneSh. I completely misread your comment.

Comment: What experiments did you run?

Comment: `int x  
unsigned int x`
i performed the operation `~x` in both cases, and noticed the results
hope that explains what i am getting at

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Maybe you should not put non-code names into code-markdown?

Comment: Sorry, can't edit the comment anymore..

Comment: What in your C book, Wikipedia or another of the >1000 sites explaining such basics did you not understand?

Comment: @EugeneSh. sorry about that, i edited it.

Comment: @MohamedZiad: So you did no research on your own - which you are expected before asking, but instead ask us to explain basics. Please notice we are not a tutoring site. Oh, and my comment should indeed provide some help. In case I was not clear enough: please read a C book and have a look at Wikipedia and possibly use a search engine. You might be surprised how many site will show up explaining those details.

Comment: Sorry I do not understand the question. The value `1` has exactly the same representation when assigned to `int` as to `unsigned int`. There are no extra `1` bits, all the other bits are `0` in both cases.

Comment: @Olaf i already know that and i think it is just a direct question, i am not seeing any broadness in it !

Comment: The size of a variable in C does not change with different _values_.  For each _type_, the size is constant.

Comment: I'd be curious to see your experimentation and how you demonstrated what you claim to demonstrate.  You could include that code in the question.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Well, Sorry as i think that i got confused which led me to this misunderstanding, but after i stuck with the facts stated in the answers i realized where my confusion came from.thanks anyhow.

Comment: OK; consider my suggestion to add the code withdrawn, but be cautious about making such claims without showing how you came to the conclusion.  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]) and include them in future questions whenever appropriate (and an MCVE is usually appropriate).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler nvm that as the thought lacks fundamental concepts so it would just be a waste of time. However; I will surely consider slowing down before i submit any preceding questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i noticed by experiment that in `unsigned int` the value of a number is represented in 32 bit even if the number is taking 1-bit space, the rest of the bits would take 0 as a value. while in `int`, the value is being put in the bits needed with just 1 more bit added for the sign. can someone please explain to me what's that?

Sure.  You're mistaken.

The C standard specifies that, as corresponding unsigned and signed integer types, `unsigned int` and (signed) `int` require the same amount of storage (C2011 6.2.5/6). The standard does not specify the exact sizes of these types, but 32 bits is a common choice.  If the representation of an `unsigned int` takes 32 bits in a given C implementation, then so does the representation of that implementation's `int`.

Furthermore, although C allows a choice from among 3 alternative styles of negative-value representation, the correspondance between signed and unsigned integer representations is defined so that the *value bits* in the representation of an `int` -- those that are neither *padding bits* nor the one *sign bit* -- represent the same place value as the bits in the same position of the corresponding unsigned integer type (C2011, 6.2.6.2/2).  Thus, the representation of a signed integer with non-negative value can be reinterpreted as the corresponding unsigned integer type without changing its numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

Machines use fixed length representations for numbers (at least common machines). Say your machine is 32-bits, that means it uses 32-bits for numbers and their arithmetic.

Usually you have unsigned representation that can represent numbers from 0 to 2^32-1 (but **every** number uses 32-bits) and 2's-complement 32-bits representation for numbers from -2^31 to 2^31-1 (such a representation uses the most significant bit for the sign). But whatever is the encoding, a number always use the same number of bits whatever is its value.

Comment: 1) there's no strict relationship between 32 bit machine and 32 bit numbers/arithmetic 2)  C standard now require unsigned integers be strictly plain binary.

Comment: There are multiple wrong assumptions and statements. Starting with the fact that most 32 bit machines don't necessarily use 32 bits for integers, to the fact that the C standard does not enforce a specific encoding, but allows for three different.

Comment: @user3528438: The standard actually **does** require binary representation for **unsigned** integers. It does not for signed integers, though.

Comment: @Olaf I agree of course, but OP as so basic question that answer need to be as basic. Do you know usual machines that use sign/magnitude? 32-bits CPU commonly name 32 bit ALU.

Comment: The question does not mention a particular architecture, so one should stick to the abstract machine as defined by the standard. But actually the question is too broad and OP does himself not do a favour asking particular question instead of trying to get the whole picture.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is very language dependent, and in some languages (like C++) the answer depends on the target CPU architecture.

many languages store both int and unsigned int in 32-bits of space.

"BigInt" support for numbers of unknown size exist in many languages.  Which behave much as you describe where they expand based on the requirements of the number being stored.

Some languages, like ruby automatically convert between the two as the math operations demand.

Comment: That's more a comments than an answer. And the question is about C, not Ruby.

Comment: Of course the answer is language dependent, for this is a language dependent question.

Comment: I was trying to be kind, since the behaviour they were describing was from a language other than C (ruby if i'm not mistaken).  And also as a newb i wasn't allowed a comment.

Comment: (and I'll own the vote down)